# How can i declare a static variable in a specific section in gnu gcc

Tags: linker, arm, gnu

i want to declare a array exception table static uint32 excp[6] in a given section .LOW_EXCEPTION defined by my linker file. how can i do this in C.

remember only this array can be accumulated in .LOW_EXCEPTION section.

thnx

Comment: `__attribute__((section(".LOW_EXCEPTION")))`

Comment: By reading the [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)? Especially the section on [variable attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes).